# R counting how many times a unique ID appears against a column containing different factors

Tags: r

I have a seemingly simple problem that I need to solve, however, I can't seem to figure out a fast, simple effective solution to it. A `df` that I am dealing with looks like this:

```
ID   type
11   payment
11   contact
11   endorse
12   payment
12   contact
13   endorse
```

What I am trying to achieve with my code is for each unique ID, how many types it corresponds to and what are they. So, it would look something like:

```
ID   n_type    what_types
11   3         payment, contact, endorse
12   2         payment, contact
13   1         endorse
```

Could someone please assist me in this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `library(dplyr);df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(n_type = n(), 
            what_type = toString(type))`. Also, `aggregate(type~ID, df, function(x) c(n_type = length(x), what_type = toString(x)))` and many other base R and `data.table` variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concise and fast option is `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(n_type = .N, what_types = .(type)), "ID"]
#   ID n_type              what_types
#1: 11      3 payment,contact,endorse
#2: 12      2         payment,contact
#3: 13      1                 endorse
```

Comment: your solution works! thank you so much. however, just confirming, does it result in a "list" class of variable for `what_types`?

Comment: Yes it does indeed.